# Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 do not work

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, mbr

After installing Ubuntu 14.04, my Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu cannot boot anymore, I get the message below, please help me fix it as I cannot use my computer any more. I tried to install boot repair through live Ubuntu CD to fix it but I cannot install it.

I appreciate your help and looking forward to hearing from you.

```
Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell! 
BusyBox v.1.21.1 (ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash) 
Enter 'help' for list of built-in commands .
(initramfs)
```

Comment: Why can't you install boot-repair? What kind of errors do you encounter with that?

Comment: There is not a trusty version of Boot-Repair, so you have to change sources to saucy. Commands in this link.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  Also do not reinstall Ubuntu with any auto options, it may delete entire hard drive. Best to have good backups and only use Something Else if reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Ubuntu installs using a legacy BIOS type boot sequence, whereas Windows 8 is most likely booting via EFI. Try interrupting the bootup on your machine with the appropriate key (F10, F9, F12, F2, or whatever it is on your particular model of pc) and selecting the Windows boot loader there rather than letting GRUB take control. By the time GRUB loads, the boot sequence has come too far to boot Windows 8.

Comment: Now I only find a black screen : windows fails to start. Oxc000001, please what to do.

Comment: Do you have or could you obtain a Windows 8 recovery disk? It sounds like you need to fix the Windows boot loader. The system is probably fine as long as you did not alter the Windows 8 partition beyond resizing/moving it during your Ubuntu installation. Note that you may have to reinstall GRUB via Live USB/CD after doing this. Instructions for that can be found here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275 in section 13.

Comment: thanks for your help, I wish I could attach a photo to make it clear, I used ububtu live cd and went to gparted grub this is what I found :

Comment: thank u, I did but I could not fix it, this is what I found using live cd gpart, what does it mean please?:1/dev/ sda2 ( a warning sign),ntfs 199 MB boot
2/ dev/sda 3 ( a warning sign) tfs 416 GB
3/dev/sda4 extended ( divided into : dev/sda5 ext 4 18 gb ;dev sda 6 ext 4 22 GB(a warning sign) andvdev sda 7 linux swap 8 G

Comment: @bilelabidi Stop creating a mess! For the 0xc000001 error message continue with your other question http://askubuntu.com/q/516062/40581

Comment: ok sorry livewire, I am really worried and in hurry to fix my pc, sorry again, can u help me please

Comment: You also ran a repair from Windows 8 recovery dvd? The GRUB reinstall won't be necessary or useful until then.