# Error message 0xc00000001 while booting Windows 8 after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, windows-8, mbr

After I installed Ubuntu 14.04, as I switch on my computer I only receive one message which is:

```
Windows Boot Manager, Windows failed to update: status 0xc00000001
```

What should I do?

Comment: Boot into ubuntu, open a terminal, and run the command `sudo fdisk -l`.  Post the output of the command here (or a screenshot of a partition manager, if you prefer that) so we can see if Windows is still there.

Comment: @tlng5 He already did http://askubuntu.com/q/515220/40581

Comment: isk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x9e18f0cd

Comment: Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1           1         992+  42  SFS
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2   *           1          26      203776   42  SFS
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda3              26       54427   436979712   42  SFS
/dev/sda4           54428       60802    51200001    5  Extended
/dev/sda5           54428       56859    19529728   83  Linux
/dev/sda6           56859       59777    23436288   83  Linux
/dev/sda7           59777       60802     8231936   82  Linux swap / Solari

Comment: How To attach a photo please to make it better. I appreciate your help. I am really worried my PC is out of order :( it is a nightmare

Comment: You just [edit] your question and add the information. `fdisk -l` does nothing more than display what partitions you have. You already did that in the other answer and could have put a reference in the question.

Answer (score 2):

According to [NeoSmart Knowledgebase](https://neosmart.net/wiki/0xc0000001/#Fix_48120c0000001_in_Windows_8) (creators of EasyBCD):

> ## Fix 0xc0000001 in Windows 8
>
> Windows 8 users may fix this boot error without an installation disc
>   by using the Windows Startup Settings (see Fix #1 below).
>
> ### Fix #1: Use Windows Startup Settings
>
> 1. Restart your computer
> 2. Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> when booting to open the Recovery screen
> 3. Select the **Advanced repair options**
> 4. Go to “Troubleshoot” and then “Advanced Options”
> 5. Select **Windows Startup Settings**
> 6. Click on Restart

## Reinstalling Windows Boot Manager with new BCD

If that doesn't work for you, you probably have invalid [BCD data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista_startup_process#Boot_Configuration_Data) after moving partitions. You can fix this by creating new BCD data with `bcdboot` from another Windows 8 installation, Windows 8 installation media or Windows 8 Recovery Disk. Have a look at the NeoSmart site, you will find Recovery Disks there. The same works for other Windows versions accordingly.

Using the `bcdboot` command isn't very complicated:

```
bcdboot C:\Windows /s S:
```

This example taken from the [Technet page about bcdboot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744347%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) would install from current `C:\Windows` source to drive `S:`. `S:` should be the drive with the boot flag  ([1](https://askubuntu.com/q/515220/40581)), which is usually called *System* on OEM installs, so `S:` may be correct.

As far as I know bcdboot is only available on Windows 7, Windows 8 and above. (Don't ask me for advice on EOL software.)

## Reinstalling GRUB

Since this will overwrite the MBR on a computer with an old partition table, you will need to reinstall GRUB, to be able to boot Ubuntu again:

- [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/q/88384/40581)

Comment: In advanced options  there is no windows start settings. There is automatic repair that I used but it says it cannot fix disk errors. Is there any another way please? Thank u

Comment: sorry I cannot reinstall Grub since all my partitions cannot be mounted :(

Comment: 1/dev/ sda2 ( a warning sign),ntfs 199 MB boot
2/ dev/sda 3 ( a warning sign) tfs 416 GB
3/dev/sda4 extended ( divided into : dev/sda5 ext 4 18 gb ;dev sda 6 ext 4 22 GB(a warning sign) andvdev sda 7 linux swap 8 G

Comment: please how to fix it

Comment: @bilelabidi I don't even know what warning signs and which application you are talking about. This could be anything from a very trivial error to a critical harddrive failure. A warning sing usually wants to tell you something, find out what that is, then ask a new question with the particular error you have found and reference previous related issues (not everyone looks into your profile). Alternatively bring this device in for repair, where people are paid by the hour to swap parts and wipe data to install new operatings systems. I will not invest anymore time in this case, good luck.

Comment: I successfully fixed ubuntu 14 through boot repair live cd and it is fine but my windows 8.1 is not booting from Grub and it shows the same errror, all my files are there :(. please see the report from boot repair :

Comment: the boot files of ( the Os now in use-ubuntu 14.04) are far from the start of the disk. your bios may not detect them. u may to retry creating a boot partition ( ext4 more than 200 mb, start of the disk) this can b performed via tools such gparted then select this partition via the { separate/boot partition} option of ( boot repair) please what does it mean??? i wanna get back my windows 8.1 :(

Comment: @bilelabidi I posted an answer on how I think you should troubleshoot the Windows boot issue. I also wrote in my last message that **I will not invest anymore time in this case**. The way you communicate - demanding solutions, while not caring how this site works and not properly reading suggested solutions - makes me regret trying to help you. Try to contacting me one more time and I'll delete all of my posts on this topic.

Comment: ok fine thanks for ur help, calm down, we are here to help each other not to fight, I will find other helpful people